# how to use jQuery on all pages

Tags: magento-1.8

I am  new in magento extension development.

I have some confusion in  how to  use jQuery on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Put the jquery.js file in the `js` folder of Magento.
add at the end of `jquery.js` this line to avoid conflicts with prototype:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

add this in the `local.xml` file of your theme or in the layout file for your custom extension.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>jquery.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Clear the cache and give it a try.
Now you should have jquery available in every page.
but don't use it like this:

```
$('#some_id').hide();
```

Leave the `$` variable for prototype.
Use it like this:

```
jQuery('#some_id').hide();
```

Comment: thanks but can u please suggest me which version i used of jquery.js file

Comment: Use any version you want, but I would suggest using the latest. 1.10.2 if you want your website to work on (IE6-8) or 2.0.3 if you don't care about IE.

Comment: thaks friends but when i am using   jQuery(document)
.ready(
  function() {

   
  
   jQuery("#save"){----} so why it not works?